# Can I change my wallpaper based on a specific calendar event?

Tags: tasker

I want my phone to very visibly show when I'm on call. I have my on-call schedule in my calendar.
I'd like to have my wallpaper change when I'm on call.

I've never used Tasker before, it sounds like it might be able to do this?
If so how?

Also open to other ideas.